# Issue while retrieving data in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, caml-query, spfx

I am trying to get data in SPFx using REST and also need to use CAML for making the query. CAML is required as I want to filter based on certain groups the user is present in, so giving that up is not an option.

I have made the code simple below but this still gives me **400 Bad request**. I get the data when I use the below url (after changing getItems to items) directly in browser.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here:

```
 this._selectedList = "List1";
 var queryString = "<View></View>";

 const options: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: { 'odata-version': '3.0'},
 body: JSON.stringify({'query': {'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'},'ViewXml': queryString }})
 };
 var getUrl = this._listsUrl + "/GetByTitle('" + this._selectedList + "')/getitems?$select=Title"; 

 return this._webPartContext.spHttpClient.post(getUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,options)
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
       debugger;
    return response.json();
 })
```

Comment: Try adding viewfields in query string.

Comment: I am getting error for AssignedTo field when I try to use in REST Url. Will, using it in View Fields can resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to query SharePoint REST API's, you should use PNPJS instead of manually crafting the requests. It provides a fluent API for the API and that will make a lot of things simpler.
For your specific case, look at [the documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/items/), especially the queries with "select", which is the equivalent of selecting specific fields of the list.
Because you're building SharePoint Framework components, you should also look at the [getting started documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/documentation/getting-started/#getting-started-with-sharepoint-framework).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have made an error in here --  `this._listsUrl`

The value of `this._listsUrl` needs to something like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists`.

So try and hard-code the URL and then check, try and modify it as below, rest of your code looks ok:

```
var getUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists
/GetByTitle('" + this._selectedList + "')/getitems?$select=Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
const options: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: {'odata-version':'3.0'},
      body: `{'query': {
        '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'},
        'ViewXml': '<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"" /></OrderBy></Query></View>'
      }}`
    };


    return this.context.spHttpClient.post(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/GetItems`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,options)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      });
```